# Compare two elasticsearch document fields from different indexes partitioned by date

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got data partitioned by day with the following simplified structure (consider objects within array being separate documents). The actual amount of documents will be more than 10 million:

/products-2019.01.01

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product1",
    "price": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product2",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Product3",
    "price": 10
  }
]
```

/products-2019.01.02

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product1",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product2",
    "price": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Product3",
    "price": 10
  }
]
```

/products-2019.01.03

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product1",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product2",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Product3",
    "price": 13
  }
]
```

My use case is that I need to compare prices between two exact days, in this case, it could be:

- 2019.01.01 vs 2019.01.02
- 2019.01.01 vs 2019.01.03
- 2019.01.02 vs 2019.01.03

Obviously, the more daily data is there, the more possible combinations are there.

If I had to compare 2019.01.01 to 2019.01.03, the query would have to return 2, because the price of product 1 and product 3 differ between these indexes.

I am looking for help to build such a query and am open to any other data model suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just aggregate by id and price in this case and add `min_doc_count` to filter out where it's not the same across two indexes

```
GET logs1,logs2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc.id+'_'+doc.price"
        },
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds very decent. I'll check it out!